# Does apache for linux process http requests as a different user?

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, lamp

I've been doing web development for about 6 months now for fun and so I never really had a reason to be secure. Now I want to change that but I'm having a hard time understanding apache file permissions. I created the server and usually just ran `var/www` with 777 permissions because I needed to get by and didn't have information worth stealing. I researched user permissions and now I have run into a problem after configuring some things. I added the apache user "nobody" to a group I created called `webserver`, I also have an ftp user in this group. I set `var/www` permissions so that "me" and the group `webserver` have full permissions on for the folder and enclosed files and other users have no rights (can't read). When I attempt to view my sample website on 'localhost' I get a permission denied message from apache, but apache has full ownership of the file so why can't it process the file, send the appropriate response the the computer which requested it, and complete the transaction? Does Apache process http requests as a different user? I'm confused.

Comment: Have you verifed that your apache process is running as the correct `User` and `Group`? Can be configured in `httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually on Ubuntu, apache run with the user `www-data`.

You can also pimp it by editing `APACHE_RUN_USER` and `APACHE_RUN_GROUP` in the `envvars` file.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, so why do people claim it runs under "nobody"? Does its folders and such belong to "nobody" but it runs under www-data?

Comment: Thank you, so would php be run by apache or will it run under its own name? I need to configure those permissions as well.

Comment: I would say it will be run by apache (so under `www-data`). I know that this is right for cgi scripts, but I am not totally sure for php.

Comment: ok, I've configured it accordingly. I'll see if everything is shiny.